# Wireless doesn't work ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless

I have ubuntu 13.04 installed on my laptop, and I have a problem. My wireless doesn't work, and I really don't know what to do. I can't give more informations because I don't know what to say...

Can you help me?

thank you!

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo rfkill list all`?

Comment: 0: hp-wifi: wireless Lan
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

Answer (score 0):

The steps to go:

1) Identify your adapter (lsusb will list all usb devices, lspci all pci devices ....)
2) Google for the appropiate driver (module) to load. Mostly, if you know what device you are trying to install will help you find a solution.
3) Make sure the device is enabled (in your bios).